# SQL Join on Int for Decimal Value Lookup Table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm doing a project in asp.net core 2.1 (EF, MVC, SQL Server) and have a table called `Orders`, which in the end will be a grid (i.e. ledger) of trades and different calculations on those numbers (no paging...so could run hundreds or thousands of records long).

In that `Orders` table, is a property/column named `Size`. `Size` will basically be a lot value from 0.01 to maybe 10.0 in increments of 0.01..so 1000 different values to start and I'm guessing 95% of people will use values less than 5.0.

So originally, I thought i would use an `OrderSize` join table like so with a FK constraint to the `Order` table on `Size (i.e. SizeId)`:

```
SizeId (Int)   Value (decimal(9,2))
1              0.01
2              0.02
...etc, etc, etc...
1000           10.0
```

That `OrderSize` table will most likely never change (i.e. ~1000 decimal records) and the `Size` value in the `Orders` table could get quite repetitive if just dumping decimals in there, hence the reason for the join table.

However, the more I'm learning about SQL, the more I realize I have no clue what I'm doing and the bytes of space I'm saving might create a whole other performance robbing situation or who knows what.

I'm guessing the `SizeId Int` for the join uses 4 bytes? then another 5 bytes for the actual decimal Value? I'm not even sure I'm saving much space?

I realize both methods will probably work ok, especially on smaller queries? However, what is technically the correct way to do this? And are there any other gotchas or no-nos I should be considering when eventually calculating my grid values, like you would in an account ledger (i.e. assuming the `join` is the way to go)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what is your main objective behind using a lookup table. If its only around your concerns around storage space, then there are other ways you can design your database (using partitions and archiving bigger tables on cheaper storage).

That would be more scalable than using the lookup table approach (what happens if there are more than one decimal field in the `Orders` table - do you create a lookup table for each decimal field?).

You will also have to consider indexes on the `Orders` table while joining to the `OrderSize` table if you decide to go through that route. It can potentially lead to more frequent index scans if the join key is not part of the index on `Orders` table thereby causing slower query performance.